# TSql script for deleting all foreign key constraints and unique constraints?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there any TSQL script for deleting all foreign key constraints and unique constraints **in a SQLServer 2008 database**?

Comment: This is a v. close question.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001103/i-need-to-remove-a-unique-constraints-that-i-dont-know-the-names-of

Answer (score 0):

You can use system table for your purpose:

1. `sys.foreign_keys`
2. `sys.key_constraints`
3. `sys.check_constraints`
4. `sys.default_constraints`

above system table have all foreign key, constraint and default column tables on your database.

you can write cursor for drop all above object of your database. your cursor must be like below query :

```
DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(250),
        @Command NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE cCons CURSOR for
SELECT name 
FROM sys.check_constraints

OPEN cCons
FETCH NEXT FROM cCons INTO @Name
WHILE @@Fetch_Status=0 BEGIN
    SET @Command = 'DROP CONTRACT '+ @Name
    EXEC(@Command)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cCons INTO @Name
End
CLOSE cCons
DEALLOCATE cCons
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate scripts with below command. Copy and paste generated script to new query window to drop all Fk and Unique constraints.

select 'ALTER TABLE ' + table_name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE in ('unique','FOREIGN KEY')